# How to rebuild when orientation changes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created application in flutter.But it didnt rebuild when orientation changes.
I want to rebuild the widgets when orientation changes from portrait to landscap or landscape to portrait.
Please give me some ideas.

Comment: As far as I know, by default it does rebuild when orientation changes. Did you make any modifications related to orientation change?

Comment: No I didnt put any code related to orientation.But it doesnt rebuild.I dont know why

Comment: Is the phone orientation-locked?

Comment: And did you verify auto-rotation is on in the device/emulator?

Comment: I can rebuild only when I scroll or touch the UI. Otherwise It didnt automatically rebuild when orientation changes

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `OrientationBuilder`

```
OrientationBuilder(
  builder: (context, orientation) {
    return GridView.count(
      // Create a grid with 2 columns in portrait mode,
      // or 3 columns in landscape mode.
      crossAxisCount: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 3,
    );
  },
);
```

You can also access the orientation from is media query

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    if (mediaQueryData.orientation == Orientation.landscape) {
      return const Text('landscape');
    }
    return const Text('portrait!');
  }
}
```